# How to burn an .img file under Linux?

Tags: burning, img, openvms

I have an .img file, where `file` reports this:

```
Files-11 On-Disk Structure Level 2 (ODS-2 OpenVMS file system)
```

How do I burn that onto CD? The image is 621MB in size, so it should fit on a CD just fine.
And I'd like to burn that under Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out: I could simply use [Brasero](http://projects.gnome.org/brasero/) to burn the image to disk. Worked fine.

*I'd still like to know how to do that with `cdrecord`, though.*

Answer (score 0):

Works also PowerIso for linux, and it's free